# Are JPA's Query objects returned by an EntityManager reusable?

Tags: java, jpa

Let's say I'm in a loop creating JPA queries:

```
for(A elem : collection) {
  emanager.createQuery("update A a set a.x=:y where a.id=:id")
          .setParameter("id",elem.id)
          .setParameter(":y", 123)
          .executeUpdate();
}
```

Can I reuse the returned `Query` instance?

```
Query query = emanager.createQuery("update A a set a.x=:y where a.id=:id");
for(A elem : collection) {
  query
          .setParameter("id",elem.id)
          .setParameter(":y", 123)
          .executeUpdate();
}
```

Does it apply for all instances of `Query`? `NamedQuery`, `NativeQuery`, etc
Of course, I'm talking about reusing an instance within the same `EntityManager`, ie, within the same transaction

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is reusable for Query. As far as I've tried working.

Comment: Thanks, do you have anything (eg: spec) to back this up? Or is it your own experience?

Comment: From JPA 2.1 spec, section "3.1.1 EntityManager Interface": _The Query, TypedQuery, StoredProcedureQuery, CriteriaBuilder, Metamodel, and EntityTransaction objects obtained from an entity manager are valid while that entity manager is open._

Comment: So they are not reusable in strict sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this exact same thing, executing the same query (update) inside a loop, and I get "data mismatch" on the 2nd execution.  So I put the createQuery inside the loop, and it works fine.  Not exactly what I would have expected.   I will say it's not JPQL - it's a NamedNativeQuery.

Answer (score -6):

Why dont you try the EntityManager methods to persist, update, remove registers to the database?

```
emanager.persist(elem); // creates a register in the database, set the annotation for autoincrement id of new registers in the Entity for better performance.

emanager.merge(elem); // updates a register in the database, chance the values of the Entity values and merge to persist changes to the register.

emanager.remove(emanager.merge(elem)); // delete registers from database, you need to merge de entity before deleting to avoid deleting problems.
```

so you can do this and will work fine:

```
for(A elem : collection) emanager.merge(elem);
```

Comment: You are making a query to update a register, want to make it on a more efficient way so you ask if you can reuse the Query instance. Well, I am telling you the most efficient way to make updates with JPA.

Comment: Your way is actually *less* efficient than what the OP does (hint: a merge needs a select and an update), and your answer doesn't tell if the query is reusable or not.

Comment: My way doesn't need any query at all, un your code you already have the collection... so you only merge the changes. Theres no query, no need to reuse nothing. Not setting parameters ( and not getting the id also) simpler code using EntityMangers implementation, faster, simpler, better.

Comment: How do you think the data gets loaded and updated in database? Black magic? A merge makes JPA load the date from database (1 select query), and update the data in database (1 update query).

Comment: sigh... the entity manager have native implementation.. its more efficient to let the EM do it even if you do the exact same because de manager handles the connection in a lower implementation level.... theres no advantage using OOP if you're going to program in a PHP style.. but is your problem... just tried to help you make something different...SORRY FOR TRYING TO HELP